# jQuery elements with attribute greater than passed variable (.filter())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I can use jQuery's .filter() for filtering by attribute. I also know that usage of such custom attributes is frowned upon since W3C's official implementation of data-thing in HTML5.

But I still want to know why this is not working.

JS:

```
$("[id^=hide]").click(function() {
    var lvl = $(this).attr('lvl');
    var id = $(this).attr('tar');

    $('#' + id).slideToggle(100);

    $('div').filter(function(lvl) {
        return $('this').attr('lvl') > lvl;
    }).slideToggle(100);
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="hide1" lvl="0" tar="1"></a>
<div id="1" lvl="0"></div>
<a id="hide2" lvl="1" tar="2"></a>
<div id="2" lvl="1"></div>
<a id="hide3" lvl="2" tar="3"></a>
<div id="3" lvl="2"></div>
<a id="hide4" lvl="2" tar="4"></a>
<div id="4" lvl="2"></div>
<a id="hide5" lvl="1" tar="5"></a>
<div id="5" lvl="1"></div>
<a id="hide7" lvl="2" tar="7"></a>
<div id="7" lvl="2"></div>
```

What I want to achieve is.
 1. Click on the link.
 2. SlideToggle the div that is close to the link.
 3. SlideToggle all other divs that have level attribute bigger than level attribute of that link.

I was also trying to do it like this:

```
$("[id^=hide]").click(function() {
    var lvl = $(this).attr('lvl');
    var id = $(this).attr('tar');

    $('#' + id).slideToggle(100);
    hideOthers(lvl);
});

var hideOthers = function(lvl) {
    $('div').filter(function(lvl) {
        return $('this').attr('lvl')> lvl;
    }).slideToggle(100);
}
```

But that's also not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I think e.preventDefault() is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcasdmjf/)**

In this line on your code  :

```
 $('div').filter(function(lvl) {
```

The `lvl` considered as index in jquery **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function, so the value of lvl inside the function is **[ 0 - 1 - 2 .... nbr_of_divs ]**.

to fix that just remove `lvl` from param and use it directly.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('lvl') > lvl;
}).slideToggle(100);
```

Removing also apostrophes ( ' ) from `$(this)` inside filter function :

**Replacing :**

```
return $('this').attr('lvl')> lvl;
```

**By :**

```
return $(this).attr('lvl') > lvl;
```

And it work, Hope that this help.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I don't know why I put $this in apostrophes. I did it correctly few lines up.

I was pretty sure I had to pass lvl into the function, but it works like a charm now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use turnery operator here:

**Like**

```
return $('this').attr('lvl')> lvl ? lvl : $('this').attr('lvl');
```